# Exit in a middle command on condition in a command chain

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a long chain of `bash` commands:

```
cmd_1 && \
cmd_2 && \
cmd_3 && \
...
cmd_k && \
...
cmd_n
```

If any of these commands fail, I want the whole chain to fail. I get that in the default shell behavior. However, I want to allow specifically `cmd_k` to fail, and if it fails, I want to `exit 0`.

I tried to use

```
...
(cmd_k || exit 0) && \
...
```

However, it won't exit from the main command chain, only from the subshell (?)

The reason I'm using a chain is due to environment limitations of running a single docker `run` command without any script files.

Comment: Off-topic: After `&&` you do not need a `\\` escaping the newline.

Comment: What is the problem with `true && (( a == 1 )) || exit 0 && echo "OK."` ? With `a=1` the `OK` is printed, with `a=2` the script exits. I think the problem is that this solution will also exits when `cmd_1` fails, maybe add this to the question.

Comment: Why do you put `&&` after `cmd_k` if you want to allow it to fail? Anyway, this looks like you should explore `set -e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason I'm using a chain is due to environment limitations of running a single docker run command without any script files.

Accordingly to [the Docker's `run` command documentation:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

> `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

You can run a series of commands by calling an inline shell script.

`bash` as the `[COMMAND]`, and `-c 'inline script'` as `[ARG...]`.

Example:

```sh
docker run --health-cmd image_foo bash -c 'cmd_1; cmd_2; ...; cmd_j; cmd_k; :'
```

The last `:` is a command that is always true, so it will ensure that your inline bash script always exit with status 0 (same as `exit 0`).

As a simple logic problem, running a series of commands, and exiting `exit 0`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# With if, then
if ! { true && true && true && true; }; then
  exit 0 # will not exit
fi

if ! { true && true &&  && false; }; then
  exit 0 # will exit
fi

if ! true || ! true || ! true || ! true; then
  exit 0 # will not exit
fi

if ! true || ! false || ! true || ! true; then
  exit 0 # will exit
fi

# With logic operators only
! { true && true && true && true; } && exit 0 # will not exit

! { false && true && true && true; } && exit 0 # will exit

{ ! true || ! true || ! true || ! true; } && exit 0 # will not exit

{ ! true || ! true || ! false || ! true; } && exit 0 # will exit
```

`true` and `false` are placeholders for your commands, that succeed or fail.

Other solution with an error trap:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'exit 0' ERR # exit 0 on an error

true # successful command
true # successful command
true # successful command
false # will trigger the ERR trap and exit 0
true # successful command
true # successful command
```

Example implementation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0
! {
    { echo $((++i)); true; } &&
    { echo $((++i)); true; } &&
    { echo $((++i)); false; } && # Will stop here at i=3
    { echo $((++i)); true; } &&
    { echo $((++i)); true; }
  } && exit 0
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that an `exit` should be avoided when the first command fails (only exit when `cmd_k` fails).

Comment: I quote @Mugen *The reason I'm using a chain is due to environment limitations of running a single docker run command without any script files.*. If he does not want to write a script in a file, but docker `run` only accept a single command. Then this command can be `bash -c 'cmd_1; cmd_2; ...; cmd_j; cmd_k;...; exit 0'` and it will do what he wants. But the question was not very clear. At first glance it looked like a logic problem. Now it turns out that poster just did not know how to run an inline bash script as a single command.

Answer (score 1):

```
(cmd_k || exit 0) && true
```

will `exit` the subshell inside the parentheses, then (because the subshell was successful) run `true`. If as you say you don't care whether `cmd_k` succeeds or not, you want simply

```
cmd_k; true
```